# How to add a last login field in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Is there a clean way to add a last-login field to the Meteor.users collection?

I can't seem to find an event that would be triggered when a user logs in.

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin

Comment: Along with `account_onlogin`, there are [`Meteor.loginWithPassword`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword) and [`Meteor.loginWith<ExternalService>`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice). Both accept a callback to register the event immediately.

Comment: @SamundraKC Thanks for the link. I guess the real answer to this question is RTFM! Please submit your comment as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is meteor onLogin which you want 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onlogin

Comment: While Accounts.onLogin is indeed triggered when a user logs on, it also seems to be triggered whenever a logged in client refreshes/resumes that connection e.g. by pressing F5 say on a browser or when meteor does a hot reload with code changes.

Answer (score 2):

Samundra KC said true, but I think that this package can also help someone;
https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status